# Is there any way to make this more compact?

Tags: java, shorthand

iI have a project that part of the goal is to have the shortest code possible. Ive done everything i can think of to make it as compact as i can but I'm wondering if there are any more shortcuts for the following code

```
public static void read(String[] input) throws IOException {
    for (String s : input) {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s)); 
        while (b.ready()) {
            String[] val = b.readLine().split(" ");
            for (String c : val) System.out.println(c);
        } 
        b.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: "compact" is relative.  You could put it all on one line but it's still the same code.  For example, IMO, your for loop is better off with the proper use of curly braces and the sysout on it's own line for clarity.

Comment: Just to follow up with what MadConan said, I would say tis better to maintain readability and sacrifice a bit of compactness, than to compact to the extreme and render it difficult to maintain and read. I would also agree in regards to the inner `for` loop; either the curly braces, or shove the `System.out.println` line down and indent one. Otherwise looks pretty good to me, frankly.

Comment: Usually I would always use curly braces and not have everything on the same line as in the code. the challenge here is to have the minimal lines possible which is why i did it that way, but thanks for the feedback. I agree in any other normal situation proper formatting is always the best way to go.Thanks

Comment: Yes. name the `read` method `rea` and `input` parameter `inpu`.

Comment: `challenge here is to have the minimal lines possible` are there any conditions regarding new lines? Like there should be new line mark after each `;` or `{`? If not you can just remove each new line mark you have in your code and get only one line...

Comment: basically i shouldn't do something like 

String[] val = b.readLine().split(" "); for (String c : val) System.out.println(c); (meant to all be on one line)

Comment: Your code has a potential resource leak.  If an exception is thrown in the body of the loop (after opening a file), then you are likely to leak the FileReader and the underlying resource descriptors.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by "compact". You can for example change

```
String[] val = b.readLine().split(" ");
for (String c : val) System.out.println(c);
```

into

```
for (String c : b.readLine().split(" ")) System.out.println(c);
```

Or use little different approach using `Scanner` class which would make your code shorter and more readable.

```
public static void read(String[] input) throws IOException {
    for (String s : input) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(s));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) 
            System.out.println(scanner.next());
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

---

You can also try this way (concept based on Christian Fries answer)

```
public static void read(String[] input) throws IOException {
    for (String s : input) 
        System.out.println(new Scanner(new File(s)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().replace(' ', '\n'));
}
```

As you can see this will not let you `close` Scanner, but since `File` resource is not `Closable` you don't have to invoke its `close` method so this approach seems safe.

Comment: Thank you so much. pretty sure its as "compact" as I'm going to get it now

Comment: The last one is cool. The second one is (with the Scanner and hasNext) is the most beautiful one: compact *and* readable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `split(" ")`, then a for loop to print each element of the result array on a line you may use

```
System.out.println(b.readLine.replace(' ','\n'));
```

that is

```
public static void read(String[] input) throws IOException {
    for (String s : input) {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s)); 
        while (b.ready()) System.out.println(b.readLine.replace(' ','\n'));
        b.close();
    }   
}
```